# how to prevent double post on click, when it takes long time to save to db?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

My problem :

if i have a simple post request where i just change some Voodoo items in db on edit:

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [SessionStateActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Edit(MonkeyJar voodooMonkey)
    {
        if (!this.service.EditMonkey(voodooMonkey))
            return RedirectToAction("Edit",voodooMonkey);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Lets say that EditMonkey takes 1.5 second to respond, while those 1.5 seconds is not over user can spam post requests to the same edit method, so only the lates edit will be saved. I want to prevent that.

I Read alot about this problem. I can ofcourse just diable submit button on submit via jquery, but isnt it a bit of hacky way of solving the problem? arent there any other solutions without disabling the button, and just skip the post request number 2...x and only take into avout the first one?

Comment: why not disable the button at point of submit and when it Action is complete re-enable the button.. it's not hacky at all in my opinion.. after all who's in control here you or the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double-click issue is typically solved in the UI, yes. If you are creating and have control over the UI, then it's definitely not 'hacky' to prevent double-clicks there using Javascript.

To me it sounds like you are wanting to prevent a situation where someone has either gone around your UI code in some way to perform additional click operations. Whether that's disabling/editing the Javascript, poor browser Javascript support, or something else.

You could do something with session state. If you only permit one edit at a time, you could do something like this (pseudocode):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[SessionStateActionFilter]
public ActionResult Edit(MonkeyJar voodooMonkey)
{
    //Prevent double-submit
    if (Session.IsEditActive)
    {
        //TODO: determine if you want to show an error, or just ignore the request
    }

    Session.IsEditActive = true;

    try
    {
        if (!this.service.EditMonkey(voodooMonkey))
        {
            //I'm thinking you need this line here in case the Redirect does the Thread.Abort() before the finally gets called. (Is that possible? Too lazy to test. :) Probably a race condition--I'd keep it for a guaruntee)
            Session.IsEditActive = false;
            return RedirectToAction("Edit",voodooMonkey);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //Ensure that we re-enable edits, even on errors.
        Session.IsEditActive = false;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: You should always enclose this kind of "flags" on a try-finally block. If EditMonkey throws an exception, you'll never get to edit it again on that session.

Comment: Updated with Joao's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Http is stateless. That said, a double post with same data is completely valid (as per the transport).

So, this leaves you with 2 options:

- Client side: disable the button, and throttle the request. This is not hacky at all. Is by far the most common solution.
- Server side: have some kind of monitor lock per session, so that same session cannot re-enter same block that is already executing.

Comparing both, I would prefer the client side option. is not 100% secure, but 99% can be accepted.